# HttpURLConnection ignores proxy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, httpurlconnection

Android 6.0 - 11.0.
СompileSdkVersion 30
minSdkVersion 23

HttpURLConnection ignores proxy - when specifying a non-existent address, it does not swear.
I need that after compiling the application, the application could send requests through proxy.
Tried the following:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "host");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port_number");


System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "user");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");

Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("***.***.***.***", 1111));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);

        connection.connect();
```

My code:

```
String getText(String url) throws IOException {


        Properties systemSettings = System.getProperties();
        systemSettings.put("https.proxyHost","***.***.***.***");
        systemSettings.put("https.proxyPort", "1490");
        systemSettings.put("https.proxyUsername", "user");
        systemSettings.put("https.proxyPassword", "pass");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

        connection.connect();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream inputStream;
        if (200 <= responseCode && responseCode <= 299) {
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } else {
            inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
        }

        BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream));

        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String currentLine;

        while ((currentLine = in1.readLine()) != null)
            response.append(currentLine);

        in1.close();

        return response.toString();
    }
```

When using this, page is not loaded at all:

```
 Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                    "password".toCharArray()));
        }
    };
    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Please tell me what I do wrong.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand your question , if you not need for using Proxy , use this code

```
httpurlconnection.openconnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY)
```

or if use proxy

```
//Proxy instance, proxy ip = 10.0.0.1 with port 8080
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
```

if you will get response 407

then try this code

```
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                "password".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Comment: I wrote that it ignores the proxy:
`
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);
`

Comment: Аfter these rows, the code is not performed.
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                "password".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);